# Express web server no response

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to run my Angular app in Server Side Rendering via Angular Universal.

This is the JS file that Angular Universal generated, I just edited the path and port:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = process.cwd();
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

The folder structure is fine, I run this on server:

```
> node .\server.js
Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4001
```

When I hit the site it just shows loading until it timeouts.

Express logs this on console:

```
DEPRECATED: DI is instantiating a token "ngmodule_material_carousel_MatCarouselHammerConfig" that inherits its @Injectable decorator but does not provide one itself.
This will become an error in v10. Please add @Injectable() to the "ngmodule_material_carousel_MatCarouselHammerConfig" class.
(node:6896) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
DEPRECATED: DI is instantiating a token "ngmodule_material_carousel_MatCarouselHammerConfig" that inherits its @Injectable decorator but does not provide one itself.
This will become an error in v10. Please add @Injectable() to the "ngmodule_material_carousel_MatCarouselHammerConfig" class.
```

**Edit:**

After removing the `@ngmodule/material-carousel` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngmodule/material-carousel) from project I still get the `Buffer` warning but now I can see the website.

Comment: Instead of `app.get('*', () => {})` try doing just `app.get(() => {})`. That is, remove the unnecessary `'*'`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/material2-carousel/issues/42) for that, it looks like the library does not support angular universal.

As a workaround, if you really want to use that library, you can avoid rendering the carousel if you are server side

**component.html**

```
<mat-carousel *ngIf="isBrowser" ></mat-carousel>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';

public isBrowser: boolean;
constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId)
{
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the [material-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngmodule/material-carousel) library. I had to copy the necessary files from the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/material2-carousel) to my project. The following files were needed:

```
carousel-slide.component.html
carousel-slide.component.scss
carousel-slide.component.ts
carousel-slide.ts
carousel.component.html
carousel.component.scss
carousel.component.ts
carousel.ts
_mixins.scss
```

These components require Angular Material so if you are not using the Angular Material in your project instead of `ng add @angular/material` which changes your project, run the following:

```
npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

And finally add the necessary components to your module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    MatCarouselComponent,
    MatCarouselSlideComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```